Dynamic related List Single Missing on Campaign object
I am trying to add Dynamic related List Single on Campaign Object but cannot do that. I have many related objects on the campaign object.
but I can add Dynamic related List Single on account and other Object.


The Dynamic Related List component (and Dynamic Forms functionality), is only available for LWC-enabled standard objects (Source: Standard Lightning Page Components )
Unfortunately at this point in time, it appears that Campaign is not yet LWC-enabled as per Used Dynamic Forms on LWC-Enabled Standard Objects.
You'll need to monitor the release notes to check when the Campaign object is LWC-enabled.
